# Counterexample to If f is one-to-one on A, then f'(x) $\neq$ 0 on A

Tags: real-analysis, functions

I'm having a hard time thinking of a counter example to

If $f$ is one-to-one and differentiable, then $f^\prime(x) \neq 0$ on A.

At first I was thinking of using a simple piece wise function but this wouldn't work because I still wouldn't have $f'(x) = 0$.

Would $\sin(x)$ where $A=(0,\pi/2)$ work?

Comment: An element of $S_3$ is also a one-to-one function from $A=\{1,2,3\}$ to itself, but makes no sense. Probably you have some assumption of $f$.

Comment: Ahh yes, the problem begins with let $f$ be differentiable.

Comment: Yes. Hence I have the tag "real-analysis". In the future should I include that in the problem as well?

Comment: Why not, it is just $A\subseteq \Bbb R$.

Comment: $x^3$ is a good example for $A=\mathbb R$.

Answer (score 2):

No, your example never has a zero derivative. What about $f(x)=x^3$, $A=\mathbb{R}$?

Comment: @amWhy I added the stipulation that $A=\mathbb R$.

Comment: Ahhh. That's really interesting. So with a saddle point you can still have a surjective function? I guess I'm used to thinking that f'(x)=0 would mean the next value will be the same but clearly this is not the case here. Wild.

Comment: @financial_physician Well there is no "next" value. It's flat, but only at one point, which has no width.

Answer (score 0):

In your example, if you set $f(x)=sin(x), \quad x \in (0, \frac{π}{2}) $ then it is not possible to prove this, as $ f'(x)=cos(x)$ and $f'(x)=0 \Rightarrow x=π/2 $ but your domain for $D_{f'}=(0, \frac{π}{2})$. The correct counter example, as many above me have mentioned before me, is $f(x)=x^3, \forall x \in R$, as $f'(x) \geq 0, \forall x\in R$. If the inequality for $f'$ contains "=" **but it only equals zero on specific points of $D_f$** then still, $f:\uparrow \Rightarrow f:1-1$, and that's where the counterexample is proving what you want.

The opposite of that is not valid, however, and an easy way to prove it is by using Rolle's Theorum (but you probably already know this)